# Set and access refs on {children} from parent with cloneElement

Tags: reactjs, ref

I'm trying to create a full page scrolling effect similar to fullpage.js.

I would like to accomplish this by using components like this:

```
 <FullPageContainer>
        <FullPageSection>1</FullPageSection>
        <FullPageSection>2</FullPageSection>
        <FullPageSection>3</FullPageSection>
 </FullPageContainer>
```

The full page container should be able to control its view and scroll to any of its children via a function `scroll()`. Scroll, keyboard, and UI elements would trigger this function.

I was thinking I could create refs within `<FullPageContainer>` and set them on the children. This way no matter how many children were nested, they would all be linked up by refs. However I am having trouble with the implementation.

FullPageContainer

```
import React from "react";

export const FullPageContainer = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  // Create one ref for each child
  let refs = children.map(() => React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>());

  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { ref: refs[index] });
    }
    return child;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(refs);
        }}
      >
        click
      </button>
      {childrenWithProps}
    </div>
  );
};
```

FullPageSection

```
import React from "react";

export const FullPageSection = React.forwardRef(
  ({
    children,
    ref,
  }: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    ref: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  }) => {
    return (
      <div
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          height: "100vh",
          width: "100%",
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

I can't seem to access the refs from FullPageContainer. From my understanding, the refs should be set once the  mounts, so I added a button to check the state of `refs` after everything renders. All of them are still coming back as undefined!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create those ref, but use ref from child instead,

Might be this what you want?

```
export const FullPageContainer = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  // Create one ref for each child
  let refs = useRef([]);

  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { ref: (ref) => (refs.current[index] = ref) });
    }
    return child;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(refs.currrent);
        }}
      >
        click
      </button>
      {childrenWithProps}
    </div>
  );
};


export const FullPageSection = ({
    children
  }: {
    children: React.ReactNode
  }) => {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          height: "100vh",
          width: "100%",
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Comment: When I tried your code, I got this error "Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?". Additionally, after I put forwardRef back in, console logging refs from the parent is still coming up empty.